# How to configure mongodb in intelliJ Idea in Mac as there is not showing any usr/local/mongodb file when you are going to brose the path

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

The integration of mongoDB in intelliJ Idea in Mac is not same with windows, Can anyone tell me that how to configure mongoDB with IntelliJ IDea in MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on IntelliJ IDEA CE 2018.2

You can configure it in Tools->Mongo plugin (After installing the mongo plugin from plugins tab)

[image]